# connect() blocked for 3 seconds after a lot of success connect()

Tags: linux, networking

I am writing a client-side application which `connect()` to a server and close it in a for loop.

The `connect()` is done in blocking-mode, and I found that some `connect()` call will block for about 3 seconds after thousands of successful `connect()`.
I used tcpdump and found some strange result: after I called the `connect()`, SYN was not sent for about 3 seconds.

What happened?

PS. I am on 64-bit Ubuntu, kernel 3.0.0-13.

Comment: How many connections are you trying to make in how much time? Are you trying to make a fixed number of connections or sustained a fixed connection rate? Either way, *how* *many* connections and *how* *long* (or at what rate)? Be as precise as you can.

Comment: the app is just a very simple test. i just want to connect() to my server as quickly as possible in blocking mode.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you aren't calling `bind` before calling `connect` (this is normal, and there's no reason you should). So before `connect`, there's an implicit `bind`. If the available range of local ports is exhausted, this `bind` can block while waiting for a port. The best solution depends on exactly what you're trying to do. See my comment for the details what would allow me to suggest a workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much, may be you are right, but it blocked after only thousands of connect(). Port number could up to 65535 theoretically, is there a port limit on linux system?

Comment: i found something, there is a port range configration on linux, /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range. see this page for detail : http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/condorg/linux_scalability.html